# custom UITableViewCell doesn't show data before showing full cell when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My application has custom **UITableViewCell** with large height 470px.
I created custom cell with fully programatically.

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
pixDealsTableViewCell *dealCell = (pixDealsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Deals" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (dealCell == nil) {

    dealCell = [[pixDealsTableViewCell alloc] init];
}

dealCell.dBusinessLogo.image = [pixUtil imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_icon"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
[dealCell.dBusinessName setTitle:@"Business Name" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
dealCell.dTimeAgo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 min ago"];
[dealCell.dHeading setTitle:@"Deals Head" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[dealCell.dDescription setTitle:@"Descriptionskjdfnkjsdnfis" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
dealCell.dImage.image = [pixUtil imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carrier.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(290, 250)];
[dealCell.dLike setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[dealCell.dShare setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

return dealCell;
}
```

This is my custom cell init method

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    NSLog(@"NEW CELL");
    customRed = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:209.0f/255.0f green:19.0f/255.0f blue:38.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    containerCell = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 700)];
    [containerCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    self.dBusinessLogo = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 60, 60)];
    self.dBusinessName = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 225, 20)];
    [self.dBusinessName setTitle:@"Business Name" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.dBusinessName.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [self.dBusinessName addTarget:self action:@selector(haveAccount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.dBusinessName setTitleColor:customRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.dTimeAgo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 50, 225, 15)];
    self.dHeading = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 80, 290, 20)];
    self.dHeading.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [self.dHeading addTarget:self action:@selector(haveAccount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.dHeading setTitleColor:customRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.dDescription = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 105, 290, 50)];
    self.dDescription.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [self.dDescription addTarget:self action:@selector(haveAccount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.dDescription setTitleColor:customRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.dImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 160, 290, 250)];
    self.dLike = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 420, 150, 40)];
    self.dLike.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [self.dLike addTarget:self action:@selector(haveAccount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.dLike setTitleColor:customRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.dShare = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 420, 150, 40)];
    self.dShare.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [self.dShare addTarget:self action:@selector(haveAccount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.dShare setTitleColor:customRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.contentView addSubview:containerCell];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dBusinessLogo];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dBusinessName];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dTimeAgo];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dHeading];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dDescription];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dImage];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dShare];

   // NSLog(@"Deals View added");

}
return self;
}
```

This is my UITableViewCell fully viewed.

[image: This is my UITableViewCell fully viewed.]

When I scroll down to next cell, It doesn't load properly.

It loads correctly after fully scrolled the cell to up

[image: When I scroll down to next cell, It doesn't load properly]

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: add your cellForRowAtIndexPath code for reference

Comment: when you alloc your cell, use initWithReuseIdentifier: or it will always create a new cell.
You can also try to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: @Imotep I registered cell in viewcontroller [dealsTableView registerClass:[pixDealsTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Deals"]; so It will not create new cell everytime. I checked with NSLog.

Comment: @mehulpatel How can i implement -layoutForSubviews? tableViewCell does not have that method?

Comment: @mehulpatel I updated post with customcell init method. Can u please explain how can i implement the layoutSubviews method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got answer. I created containerCell view with height of 700. But cell height is 470 only. 
I changed that containerCell view height to 470. Its fixed my problem. :)